# Fill a argument with tab file values in bash

Tags: bash

I need to creat a bash file in order to run a certain command on a server.

Here is one of the lines

```
Programm/programm.pl -k 1 -q --acc_number
```

where `--acc_number` needs a `Comma-separated list` of  accession numbers, e.g. --acc_number Number13JJ2,Number0090D93,Number088DF.

but I actually have a file calle `file_acc_number` where I have each of the accession number in line such as :

```
Number13JJ2
Number0090D93
Number088DF
```

does someone have an idea how to parse this tab file and to directly put the accessio number in a comma-separated way and get :

```
Programm/programm.pl -k 1 -q --acc_number Number13JJ2,Number0090D93,Number088DF
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please show us what you tried!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `paste`:

```
Programm/programm.pl -k 1 -q --acc_number `paste -s -d, file_acc_number`
```

Try running `paste -s -d, file_acc_number` first to understand whether you get what you require.

Answer (score 1):

with an inline expansion maybe? Like this

```
Programm/programm.pl -k 1 -q --acc_number  $(sed -z 's/\n/,/g' file_acc_number)
```

Make sure your file `"file_acc_number"` has no "new line" at the end of it.

With this, you will replace the "new line" character with a comma on the fly without affecting the original file.